# How to update local Master branch in VS/Git from Source Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am working on VS 2017 Professional Edition and trying to update my local Master branch with recent code change went into master.

I do see multiple options as Fetch, Pull request, Push.  I just need to get recent code from Git to my local.

How  to update local Master branch in VS/Git from Source Git?

Comment: First, it's important to recognize that Git is *NOT* "client/server"; it's not "master/slave".  Each git repo (including "local" and "remote") are *PEERS* of each other.  Second, you should be able to do a "pull".  The command line equivalent is `git pull origin master`.  Third, you can use *ANY* Git client, not just the built-in MSVS Git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS 2017, you can use the `Sync` option in `Team Explorer` to get latest of origin/master down: [image: Team Explorer - Home]

I personally don't like using VS's Git UI, as I don't feel in control of what's happening in the background.

You can just do a `git pull` in the console to get the latest master changes locally.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ivan, I was little confused with Pull and Pull Request. This helps

Comment: I can appreciate why the two would be confusing.
`Pull`-ing the `origin` branch updates the local copy with the latest changes.
A `pull request` happens when you want to merge your local changes to an origin branch (usually on a shared/public repository) and you need the owner of the repository to approve the merge.

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful on sharing the differences. I am using only " Pull " to merge Source - Master branch to my local Master branch. It worked